# Firefox displays 3 columns in a table, IE8 only 2

Tags: image, firefox, internet-explorer-8, html-table

Would love some help here... Firefox displays the last column in the table (an image they click on to edit their email address, it's a link), and IE8 displays nothing for the last column (doesn't even appear to display a column!)  I've left out other rows in the table, but similar stuff happens.

Anyone know why?

```
<table class="profile-display">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right; color: red;"> Email address: </td>
    <td class="profile-content"> <?php echo("$evar"); ?> </td>
    <td> <a href="profile_change.php?edit=13"  
         <img src="../images/writegreen.png" class="profile-edit" alt="Edit" 
          title="Edit Email Address"
   border="0" />
         </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you add the css for the profile-display, profile-content and profile-edit classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag is missing its `>`. That will cause a browser to not recognize the end of the tag until the first `>` it sees, which is the end of the `img` tag. Frankly, I'm surprised that Firefox shows the `img`.

Edit: Other common causes of this problem are missing quotes and misspelled tags.

Comment: It may seem stupid, but this is a common problem, and any HTML author has to know to watch for this and recognize its symptoms.